# Big O notation given different sizes of input in worst, average and best case

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a question about big O notation when you have a specific number of input n. 
Let's say I have 3 algorithms with time complexity of O(n), O(n^2) and O(n log n) respectively. Assume that all 3 algorithms above take a, b and c seconds for the worst, average and best case given the input of n. What could be the actual time of these 3 algorithms given the input of 2*n ?
Based on my understanding it should be: 
    - O(n): 2*a , 2*b and 2*c. 
    - O(n^2) : a^2, b^2 and c^2. 
    - O(n log n): a log a, b log b and c log c.
My questions are: 
    * Are my solutions correct?
    * If the above solutions are correct, would that be the same for theta and omega
    * What could be the reasons that the above solutions are not right?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for problems pertaining to actual code. For theoretical questions consider Quora or the [CS site](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

No, a, b and c are still functions of n. You are composing O with a with n. i.e. O(a(n)), but the answer is a(n).

Comment: My bad I was not very clear. I mean for an algorithm with O(n) and given the input of size n the worst case it takes a seconds ( a is just a number like 1,2,3) average it takes b seconds and best case it takes c seconds of input size n. My question is how long will it take for the same algorithm given the input of size 2*n

Comment: Let O(n^2)=n^2, let a=9, the minimum time it takes for n=9. then for 2*n=18, O((2*n)^2)=324, while O(a^2)=81. (a,b,c) are functions since their value depends of a particular value of n.